# Is there a way to setup a manual testing hierarchy in Jira that can be used iteratively?

Tags: jira

Is there a way to setup a manual testing hierarch in Jira that can be used iteratively?
For example, the following would be a hierarchy checklist:

```
Testing
Windows, iOS
Windows Desktop, Windows Web, iOS Desktop, iOS Safari
```

And then once checklist is complete, be able to clone the entire hierarch and start again on a new iteration?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the below sites, there is no good way to setup hierarchy in Jira. There are plugins, but it seems they have been stopped or abandoned. Of course there is [Structure](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.almworks.jira.structure), but that's not free and may not be the thing you are looking for.

- [Epic Feature User Story Tasks Hierarchy in Jira](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/14335/epic-feature-user-story-tasks-hierarchy-in-jira)
- https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/323310/how-do-i-create-epic-story-task-hierarchy
- https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/29386/want-to-create-a-multi-level-hierarchy
- https://confluence.atlassian.com/agile/jira-agile-user-s-guide/working-with-epics

Answer (score 0):

### Don't Write Separate Stories/Tickets Just for Testing

In general, if you're using Jira (or any ticketing system) to drive task-level details, then you aren't really doing agile user stories. Instead, your routine testing tasks should be part of your "Definition of Done" for testing, and you may not even need testing-specific stories.

In pull-based work queues, testers should pull a user story into the testing stream whenever it's been marked *ready* by the developers. Standard tests and implicit elements of the Definition of Done are then performed, and any checklists or documentation that needs to be attached to the ticket can be added as a file attachment or linked in the ticket's notes section.

I strongly discourage teams from having separate testing stories because they are *not* separate features. Rather, testing is an intrinsic part of ensuring that a feature is *done*, and any feature that is tested or that fails testing is *not-done*.